# Add command to bash history every time I log in

Tags: bash

I'd like to add a command to my bash history, from my bashrc. I'd like to make sure this command is always there.

I tried to do this, but it appears that changing the history from the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` scripts is not possible.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
history -s mycommand and its arguments
```

to your configuration file.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid adding the same thing to the history twice without using ignoredups for the whole file? Kind of like doing `export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups`, then adding a command, committing the history, and resetting HISTCONTROL to what it was before?

Comment: I don't understand why, because the help of the command `history` says nothing abou it, but this seems to have erased my history! Is there any way of adding a command without erasing the history?